# Is there a way to discard an APC queue?

Tags: winapi, asynchronous, wait, apc

I use QueueUserAPC() function to add my asynchronuous procedure calls to the APC queue of my threads.

Let's say I have queued 10 calls to a thread, and while executing one of the calls after the thread entered SleepEx(), for some reason I decided not to execute next APCs. My primitive and simplistic solution to this problem is to wrap all the calls with an if block checking a global variable, and execute the block only if this condition variable is (or not) set.

Is there a better way to do this? Can I discard the APC queue of a thread so that the other calls queued in it will not be called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no user-mode way to remove items from the APC queue.  (You can from kernel mode, but even there, removing items from the APC queue is only done in teardown situations.)  In any case, `QueueUserAPC` doesn't return a usable handle that you could cancel, and flushing the queue entirely is a **bad idea** because other code might have put items on the queue that you're not aware of.

Comment: I believe that the thread running the async calls must have the chance to decide what to do with its own queue. Other code pushing items to the queue may not know the internal state of that thread. It should be the thread's responsability to call the async functions, or to discard them. But well, I think one can implement their own queue; just queue code to take a pointer to a function and another one for the parameter, and another handle to the wait function. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Oregano - QueueUserAPC was (in Raymond Chen's terms) designed with "kernel-colored glasses".  The entire APC mechanism is built around allowing the kernel to invoke user-mode callbacks while the thread is blocked.

Comment: @EricBrown - I'm not even sure you can easily do it from kernel mode.  KeRemoveQueueApc() isn't an exported function even though KeInsertQueueApc() is..